# React Router v4 not rendering components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Having an issue with React Router v4 rendering components. On initial load of the application it will render the correct component corresponding to the URL However, any subsequent `Link` clicks will not render the desired component.

**Libraries**

- [React Router: 4.2.2](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)
- React: 15.6.1
- React DOM: 15.6.1
- -- just to mention libraries in case of impact --

  - React Redux: 5.0.6
  - Redux: 3.7.2
  - Material UI: 0.19.0

Going to omit some `imports` for sake of brevity

**Site Structure**

```
index.jsx
  |
  App.jsx
    |
    Auth.jsx
      |
      Layout.jsx
        <Routes />
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import store from './store.js';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createBrowserHistory();

import App from './containers/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Auth from '../components/Auth.jsx';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Auth />;
  }
}
```

**Auth.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './Layout.jsx';

export default function Auth(props) {
  //this Has a render function to render a Loader, Error Page, or the Layout
  return <Layout />;
}
```

**Layout.jsx**

There's more complexity involved here with rendering out the entire application. I'm going to leave the other layout components commented out and just have some Links and a `Switch` component to get that working before making items more modular.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Overview from './views/overview/Overview.jsx';
import Home from './views/home/Home.jsx';

export default class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="layout">
        {/* <TopBar /> */}
        {/* <AppBar/> */}
        {/* <Drawer>
              <MainMenu/>
            </Drawer> */}

            <Link to="/">HOME</Link>
            <Link to="/overview">Overview</Link>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/overview" component={Overview} />
            </Switch>

        {/* <Routes /> */}
        {/* <Footer /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Routes.jsx**

This is what I'm intending the routes components to look like.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './views/home/Home.jsx';
import Overview from './views/overview/Overview.jsx';
import Admin from './views/admin/Admin.jsx';
import NotFound from './NotFound.jsx';

export default function Routes(props) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/overview" component={Overview} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Is there something I'm missing to get components to render clicking `Link`? I'm not getting any console errors or anything telling me there's an issue. So not sure if components are not wrapped correctly or what may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like what was happening is that with Redux integrations was blocking updates.

Need to:

`import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';`

`export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App))'`

[Documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer. I was having the same exact problem and this fixed my issue too. Thanks again and good luck with your app!

Comment: I am currently setting up my react app and came across this issue. 

I have not added any redux functions yet. 

I think my question is which component do i need to put `withRouter`?

I am setting up my routing using config: [https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pure: false` in connect.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give it a try and review the results. I went with the `withRouter` option solely based on the React Router v4 documentation. But I'm also curious on using the `pure: false` setting.