# How to troubleshoot React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I've just implemented React Router 4 in my React/Redux app which was using multiple entry points up to this point.

I changed my code to have a single entry point and set up a catch-all route on the server side so that react router would handle requests on the client side.

Initially, everything seems to work OK but it takes a long long time before the right component is displayed. As soon as I click the link, I see the URL in the browser address bar change immediately but I have to wait sometimes more than 10-15 seconds before the right component is loaded.

I've also noticed that after a click or two, it stops working all together.

I don't get any errors and I put a break point on the server to see if I'm somehow hitting the backend when I click a link but looks like I'm not even going to the backend.

How can I debug/troubleshoot this? React Router is just a bunch of components and there's not much code to speak of that I can debug.

Has anyone experienced this issue? I'd appreciate any ideas you may have. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, but there might be problem with your client side routes configuration. You can also take help of the react dev tools which is the chrome extension to see whether mounting and unmounting is going on somewhere in a loop.

Comment: Thanks. I'll dive deeper to see what's going on.

Comment: I would also consider adding a logging function to your middleware that prints the state on each change so you can see if there's something unexpected (like a long DB query or network timeout) that is blocking something like `const store = createStore(_persisted, applyMiddleware( thunk, logger, crashReporter ))` where the logger just prints the state: `const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.log('[DISPATCHING] %s', action.type)
  const result = next(action)
  console.log('[NEXT STATE]', store.getState())
  return result
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in this post: [React Router v4 not rendering components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007214/react-router-v4-not-rendering-components?rq=1)

Because I'm using Redux, I needed to use `withRouter`.